# How to make JavaScript affect only the code between specific tags

Tags: javascript, html, html-entities

This is the source of my simple HTML page (save as .html file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function convert(){
 var ele1 = document.getElementById("somewhere");
 var replaced;
 replaced = ele1.value;
 replaced = replaced.replace(/&/ig, "&amp;");
 replaced = replaced.replace(/</ig, "&lt;");
 replaced = replaced.replace(/>/ig, "&gt;");
 replaced = replaced.replace(/'/ig, "&#039;");
 replaced = replaced.replace(/"/ig, "&quot;");
 ele1.value = replaced;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<textarea cols="70" id="somewhere" rows="15" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(250, 250, 250); border: 2px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);"></textarea><br />
<input onclick="convert();" type="button" value="Encode" />
</body>
</html>
```

What this page does is, any code put in the textarea is HTML-encoded/escaped when the "Encode" button is clicked — essentially all instances of `&`, `<`, `>`, `'` and `"` in the input code are replaced with their respective HTML entities.

How do I modify the JavaScript code in the page, so that only the input code between `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags is modified as aforementioned?

---

**EDIT:** As I see it I wasn't clear. First you need to save the HTML code I gave above into a .html file and open it in a browser. Then you will see a textarea/textbox with an "Encode" button below it.

Any code put into the text area is escaped when the "Encode" button is pressed.

I want to modify the JavaScript code in the HTML code above, so that (for instance) if I put the following code in the textbox:

```
It's mine.
<pre>
<input onclick="convert();" type="button" value="Encode" />
</pre>
It's also mine.
```

and hit the "Encode" button, only the code between `<pre>` tags is escaped. I hope I am clear this time.

---

Hope I am clear, and can get some help. Thanks.

Comment: The hole idea of escaping HTML this way is a really bad idea, if you are doing this at least use a well know library for escaping html

Comment: @ntziolis : I am escaping HTML because the `<pre>` has issues with some charachers, especially the `<`. So, the aforementioned code is all I need, right?

Comment: Actually, `&#039;` is not an [entity reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.2) but a [(numeric) character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.1).

Comment: @Gumbo: Oh! I don't know how to code. That's the HTML/JS I grabbed from elsewhere because I needed it. I thought HTML entities is a common name. Sorry abt that.

Comment: @badlearner Unfortunately, it is. But it has become the de-facto term just like everything can referred to as a [tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#didx-element-2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insead of using:

```
var ele1 = document.getElementById("somewhere");
```

You could use:

```
var ele1 = document.getElementsByTagName("pre");
```

However this might return multiple elements since there could be multiple `<pre>` sections in your html.

But again, if your goal is to produce a safe output, escaping is not a preferred solution. Have a look at Markdown for example:
http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction (the link). I actually forgot that adding 4 spaces or a tab before each line of the code is all I need. Damn! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure into what you're trying to convert. `ele1.innerHTML` parses the HTML exactly how it should to be parsed. Ie. `<` will be converted to `&lt;`, which is valid HTML.

**Edited**

```
function convert(){
  var txt=document.getElementById('somewhere');
  txt.innerText=txt.innerHTML;
  return;
}
```

Quotemarks and hipsals are valid html, but if you want have them replaced:

```
var txt=document.getElementById('somewhere');
var txti=txt.innerHTML;
txti=txti.replace(/\"/g, "&quot;");
txti=txti.replace(/\'/g, "&#039;");
txt.innerText=txti;
```

Comment: May be I wasn't clear before. I have edited my question to be more clear. Please take a look.

Comment: @badlearner I've edited my answer. This is what you've tried to implement?.

Comment: Partly yes. Yours + ntziolis' answer = complete answer to my question. Thanks a lot Teemu!